# Bamboo: How can I set PATH/environment variables in the root process of the build?

Tags: path, environment, bamboo

(Bamboo 5.5.1, Windows build agents)

Our Bamboo server runs builds for a multitude of projects with varying requirements to PATH/environment variables. A prime example is some jobs requiring Python 3, others requiring Python 2. Python 'pip' activates the Python interpreter by invoking 'python.exe', without no path given to select Python 2 or 3; it takes whatever comes first in PATH - which may be the wrong one, so pip fails.

We have created an executable to be run first in every job, configuring the environment by setting up the proper 'toobox' for the job (here, a 'toolbox' is a file which lists all the tools with their versions; a description file specifies the enviroment required by each tool.) The exeuctable sets up e.g required file system links for all tools to work properly. But it cannot set PATH/environment variables. Or rather: it can set/modify them, but all is lost when the process running the executable terminates - a process cannot change the environment of its mother process. Following tasks (in the same job, on the same agent) will inherit the intial, umodified PATH/environment from the mother process.

So we have the 'set up toolbox' executable generate a script file (.bat) as output, for the mother process to run as a script, so that the appropriate PATH/environment settings are inherited by later tasks (child processes) in that same job.

Appearently, in Bamboo, a script task is NOT a script. I made a small test job:

Task 1 is an executable generating the .bat file with all the SET commands (including PATH).

Task 2 is is a Bamboo "script" task running the generated file. The log shows that it has been executed properly; the SET commands are executed.

Task 3 is another Bamboo script task displaying all environment variables, including PATH.

But neither %PATH% nor other environment varibles have been changed by the Task 2 "script". The behaviour is as if the root process starts a child process to run the Task 2 script (rather than sourcing the file specified), and environment changes to that child process are discarded as soon as the "script" interpreting is completed. It doesn't behave like a script at all (hence the ""s!), but as a child process.

When I do the three steps in a cmd.exe shell: 1) generate setvars.bat, 2) run setvars.bat, 3) SET, to show the current variables, - then everything is fine, exactly as expected. THAT is the behaviour I am after; I want the Bamboo root process to do the same things as cmd.exe does.

Is there any way I can make the root process source the script (i.e. the .bat file), to change its own PATH/environment for its future child processes?

Note 1: The Python 2/3 example is just an example of the kind of issues; a Python-specific solution would cover only a small fraction of the needs.

Note 2: The executable CAN set the permanent PATH/variables in the registry, but that won't help tools that do not read the registry but relies on values inherited from its mother process. To make registry changes effective, you would have to restart the Bamboo agent process.

Note 3: If the following tasks were scripts, each and every one of those (rather than the root process) could source the generated .bat file. This won't work for 'binary' tasks, or tasks that for other reasons have no capabilities for modifying their own environment.

Note 4: The PATH/enviromnent changes are highly dynamic; they can NOT be configured in the job specification (e.g. tool locations may vary dependent on which agent runs the job), and they can NOT be specified at the agent level (different jobs have different requirements, e.g. to PATH order).

I am not bound to use the old MS-DOS .bat command format; if there is some other command language I can use to set the root process environment, that is fine with me - but there must be a way to make the root process itself run the commands, not in a child process.

A couple older questions somewhat similar to this is being answered by "Use a script task!" That is exactly what I am doing. If that is the answer, please show me how to run one script task modifying the environment, followed by another task displaying the change. It doesn't work that way for me!